# AngularJS: require with bindToController, required controller is not available?

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive where I user require and bindToController in the definition.

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

    angular.module('core')
        .directive('formValidationManager', formValidationManager);

    function formValidationManager() {
        return {
            require: {
                formCtrl: 'form'
            },
            restrict: 'A',
            controller: 'FormValidationManagerCtrl as fvmCtrl',
            priority: -1,
            bindToController: true
        };
    }
}());
```

According to the angular docs:

> If the require property is an object and bindToController is truthy,
>   then the required controllers are bound to the controller using the
>   keys of the require property. This binding occurs after all the
>   controllers have been constructed but before $onInit is called. See
>   the $compileProvider helper for an example of how this can be used.

So I expect that in my controller:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('core')
        .controller('FormValidationManagerCtrl', FormValidationManagerCtrl);

    FormValidationManagerCtrl.$inject = ['$timeout', '$scope'];

    function FormValidationManagerCtrl($timeout, $scope) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.API = {
            validate: validate
        };

        //vm.$onInit = activate;

        function activate() {
        }

        function validate() {
            $scope.$broadcast('fvm.validating');
            var firstInvalidField = true;
            Object.keys(vm.formCtrl).forEach(function (key) {
                var prop = vm.formCtrl[key];
                if (prop && prop.hasOwnProperty('$setTouched') && prop.$invalid) {
                    prop.$setTouched();

                    if (firstInvalidField) {
                        $timeout(function(){
                            var el = $('[name="' + prop.$name + '"]')[0];
                            el.scrollIntoView();
                        }, 0);
                        firstInvalidField = false;
                    }
                }
            });
            return firstInvalidField;
        }
    }
})();
```

vm.formCtrl will be populated with the form controller. However, it is undefined. Why is it undefined? Additionally, I tried to access it in the $onInit function but the $onInit function never got called. What am I doing wrong?

I am using the directive like so:

```
<form novalidate name="editUserForm" form-validation-manager>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is your issue, but I think your directive declaration should look like this:

```
controller: 'FormValidationManagerCtrl',
controllerAs: 'vm',
```

rather than:

```
controller: 'FormValidationManagerCtrl as fvmCtrl',
```

Comment: no, this is not the issue. vm is just a variable referencing the 'this' in the controller. I had the correct name in the view.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is related to the angular version. I was in 1.4.6 which did not support this. I have upgraded to 1.5.0 in which the code in the OP is working great.